# symfony2: How to prevent FOSRestBundle from adding _api to route names and /api to urls?

Tags: symfony, routes, fosrestbundle

I have an `EventApiController` class that looks like the following

```
Class EventApiController
{
    public function getAction($event_id)
    {
      // ...
    }
    public function putAction($event_id)
    {
      // ...
    }
}
```

Using the Friends of Symfony bundle's route generate i am expecting the route to look like

```
CalendarBundle_get_events   [GET]  /api/v1/events/{event_id}.{_format}                                                                                       
CalendarBundle_put_events   [PUT] /api/v1/events/{event_id}.{_format}
```

However it seems like the Route generator automatically adds a post fix /api to all of the routes so the route looks like.  And the documentation does not show this as the expected behaviour as well.

```
CalendarBundle_get_events_api   [GET]  /api/v1/events/{event_id}/api.{_format}                                                                                       
CalendarBundle_put_events_api   [PUT] /api/v1/events/{event_id}/api.{_format}
```

Does anyone know how to get rid of the /api post fix from the generated link? I am using FOS/ResutBundle version 1.3.1

My config.yml for fos_rest

```
fos_rest:
  routing_loader:
    default_format: json
    include_format: true
  view:
     view_response_listener: true
```

And the routing.yml looks like this in my Bundle

```
event_api:
   type:     rest
   resource: "@CalendarBundle/Controller/EventsApiController.php"
   prefix:   /api/v1
   name_prefix: CalendarBundle_
```

Comment: add your `fos_rest` configuration and the relevant routing parts to the question pls.

Comment: could you please update the `[GET|PUT]` routes with the real ones from your application so we can see in how far they match the configuration i.e. output of `app/console router:debug | grep CalendarBundle_`. Currently the `prefix` of `event_api` routing is not in there... or did you post the wrong routing config?

Comment: I wasn't able to find any evidence of code that's adding `_api` to route names or `/api` to urls in FOSRestBundle's code i.e. the **[RouteLoader](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/tree/master/Routing/Loader)**. To me it looks like there's another bundle responsible for this behavior. Have you annotated controller class/actions somehow additionally?

Comment: nope the controller action is just a simple getAction(), thanks for the help though I will investigate further will post the result as i find it.

Comment: Did you add `implements ClassResourceInterface` and/or add a `@RouteResource("Event")` annotation ? See [implicit resource name definition](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/5-automatic-route-generation_single-restful-controller.md#implicit-resource-name-definition)

Comment: What happens if you set `fos_rest.routing_loader.include_format: false` ? Do you i.e. `/api/v1/events/{event_id}/api` ? don't forget to clear the cache.

Comment: yep that is what i got /api/v1/events/{event_id}/api  without the .{_format}

Comment: you sir is a genius implementing @RouterResource("Events") does the trick :D

Comment: Ah i could have seen that earlier .. i was fooled by the fact that the class name in the example was `EventController` though you said it's named `EventApiController` in the sentence before. That totally makes sense now! It was the `Api` in the controller name that was responsible for the behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the `Api` in `EventApiController` that gets detected as route resource by **FOSRestBundle**.

You can override the resource name like this in order to prevent the `_api` route name and `/api` urls:

```
use FOS\RestBundle\Routing\ClassResourceInterface;

/**
 * @RouteResource("Event")
 */
Class EventApiController implements ClassResourceInterface
{
```